# Are there infinitely many $k$ for which $\frac{\sigma(k)}{k}$ is a rational square where $ \sigma(k) $ and $k$ both are square?

Tags: elementary-number-theory, square-numbers, divisor-sum

Is There some one who can show me if  there are infinitely many $k$ for which

$$\frac{\sigma(k)}{k}$$ is a rational square where $\sigma(k)$ and $k$ both 
are square ?

Note :$\sigma(k)$ is sum divisor function of $k$

Thank you for any help

Comment: Note: you are essentially asking whether there are infinitely many integers $n$ with $\sigma(n^2)$ a square.

Comment: yes, that is what i meant

Comment: We can at least say that n must be composite.

Answer (score 2):

This is completely unknown.

Your question boils down to whether $\sigma(n^2)$ is square infinitely often, and we have no idea. The [OEIS](http://oeis.org/A006532) has a list of known cases, but it is not known to be infinite. I would say there is not even a hint of an idea as to how to proceed towards proving there are or are not infinitely many, and both directions are completely unknown.

Comment: see http://mathoverflow.net/questions/212517/are-there-infinitely-many-k-for-which-frac-sigmakk-np-and-p-is-an#comment526805_212517  where Noam thinks it should be possible to prove something; and is the reason for this question being posted here. Note that the problem was attributed to Fermat by Jacques Ozanam, see pages 54-58 in volume I of Dickson's three volume History of the Theory of Numbers

Comment: hmmm... actually, Noam just says "perhaps this follows from known results" referring to there being infinitely many

Comment: and the question that you are indicated it is my question